# Scholarly reference for IDW variable radius algorithm

Tags: algorithm, gis

I'm trying to come up with a scholarly reference for the variant Inverse Distance Weighting algorithm where only the closest N points are used.  The [Wikipedia page for IDW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_distance_weighting) lists it at the bottom under the heading [Modified Shepard's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_distance_weighting#Modified_Shepard.27s_Method), but the information there is pretty sketchy.

This algorithm is in common use in the GIS world (see the bottom of this [ArcGIS Desktop Help](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgiSDEsktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Implementing_Inverse_Distance_Weighted_%28IDW%29) page for a simple description).  Does anyone know of a better (preferably authoritative) reference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The citation in the Wikipedia page](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=800186.810616) is the original paper by Shepard, and is heavily cited. It does not get more authoritative than that. Otherwise, a good book on remote sensing or GIS could be an adequate reference.

The modified Shepard version is attributed to Franke and Nielson [in this paper](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/nme.1620151110/abstract), and is also heavily cited in the literature (you can get an idea of citation counts in Google Scholar).